# How to set up Firebase-enabled Android app builds versus database access

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In the [Organizing your Firebase-enabled Android app builds](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html) there is a post that reads:

> Small team, simple app
>
> It's also important to note that, with this configuration, you will be
>   working against all the same data during development as your active
>   users on your fully released app. This may not be the safest thing, if
>   you intend to disrupt your Realtime Database data or experiment with
>   Remote Config values during development!

I want to ask about how to use the Firebase database but not use the Real time database release data version, the data that the release APK produce.

Was thinking that there could be duplicate databas roots like root-release and root-debug. So in the root-debug I can trow in whatever I need to debug and of course develop and test future keys.

Would like some thought on this how to do this safer so the debug APK version never can accidentally destroy real time release data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your real-life data, which is great. However, you need to experiment a few things, so you need a copy of the database generated where you can play with data without the risk that you ruin real-data. This database needs to be periodically generated, so that your local copy will never differ too much from the live database.

This will solve the problem of having data risk at development phase. However, real-life data can be ruined in many other ways:

- hacker
- physical damage
- wrong script
- bugs in your code
- mistakes of users

To cope with these problems you will need to regularly generate backup databases as well. Some teams are using the backup database and it is debatable whether that is too risky. I am on the opinion that an untouched backup copy is helpful.

So, you will need to have a dev and a prod environment and possibly a staging too. dev will be linked to the dev db, prod to the live db. The staging environment could be connected to the dev db, but you can have a separate db for that as well. The role of staging is to have a stable place for unreleased code synchronization in case you are a member of a team or you intend to present your work to remote viewers.

Comment: Great thanks when you say **dev and a prod environment** do you mean two different android studio projects? I feel I need to read up on this, can you give link to some reading how to set this up? Is using premium GitHub a good place for this?

Comment: By dev environment I refer to the copy you are working on on your computer. By prod environment I refer the copy on the remote server your users will be downloading and using. You need to version them separately, git is a good tool for that purpose, GitHub is a great choice, just like GitLab. Sources: https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html, http://inaka.net/blog/2014/12/22/create-separate-production-and-staging-builds-in-android/. If this post answered your question, then you might consider accepting it. Cheers.